# Power BI - DAX measure. Slicer values from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

Three tables. Many to one relationship between A - X, and B - X  (cross filter direction both selected in Power BI)

As screenshot below displays, in PBI I'd like to have a measure called Return %. My date slicer works fine (TableX[Date]), it returns per day sales amount and untis sold/returns.

However, the second slicer (TableA[Product]) only returns accurately Sales. In this instance:

```
100+120 = 220
```

Which DAX measure would enable the second slicer to filter correctly through table B? I've tried with:

```
return% = calculate(sum(B[Returns]) / sum(B[Units sold]), SELECTEDVALUE(A,[Product])
```

Without any results..Please find below Screenshot for illustration.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: you got 11% result? here what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Siva, The calculation is just 1/9 = 11% (for illustration purposes).

I'm trying to replicate this with two slicers, with values from table A and X, in Power BI.

Thanks

Comment: can you attach data sheet file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
return% =
VAR selection_A_product = SELECTEDVALUE ( A[Product] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( B[Returns] ) / SUM ( B[Units sold] ),
        B[Product] = selection_A_product
    )
```